# Remove 'switch selection' pop-up from Select Features tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select, overlapping-features

I'm using the 'select features' (clicking with the select features by rectangle option) tool in ArcGIS 10, and when multiple features are present, instead of selecting them all, one feature is selected, and this little toolbar/icon/drop-down menu thing shows up (looks like a 'switch selection' icon) and lists the other items that should have been selected. I'm sure there are plenty of instances where this would be useful, but almost exclusively, I find it unhelpful at best.
[image: selection menu thing]

Is there a way to turn this off? (Or a name for the menu/tool object to better search for a solution? I looked at the selection options and general options and found nothing. The ArcGIS help on the select tool doesn't make any reference to it, and I don't know what it's called to find any reference to it.

Comment: That is the selection chip. I think it is an incredibly useful tool for choosing which of overlapping features at a location you want to select.

Comment: Do you mean selecting features within same feature class? I don't think you can turn that off

Comment: Perhaps making layers non selectable can help?

Comment: You must be in an edit session. That doesnt come up when just doing a normal select

Comment: It is in an edit session, thanks for the name of it, that turned up more results

Comment: The Selection Chip (@polygeo) only displays when I use Editor, Edit Tool. I don't see the Chip when I use Select Features. The Chip only displays when I select stacked features during an edit session. ArcGIS 10.4

Comment: I'm stuck with 10.0 at work, the selection chip comes up using the select features tool when it's clicked, but only in an edit session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from everyone's comments, your description, and my own experience of using the Selection Chip from ArcGIS 10.0 through 10.5, it seems like the behaviour has been the same since it first became available, and most users are happy with it.  I actually think it was one of the most useful bits of editing functionality introduced by ArcGIS 10.0

I am not aware of there being, or ever having been, a way to turn off the Selection Chip.

My recommendation would be to upgrade to 10.5, to get access to ArcGIS Pro, and determine whether they prefer its editing environment and tools.

If they are still not happy, then you could submit or vote for an ArcGIS Idea to have it become the way they want.

Comment: I do see the value of it, and certainly don't think it should be rolled back, just hoping there was a less than obvious dialog to turn it off. knowing that it only occurs in edit sessions is a simple enough way to avoid it